# Responsive images

Tags: html, css

I'm not looking for a inventive solution on the images, I've read plenty of content about loading images etc.

I'm just doing some basic responsive design and want to load a large image and just squash it down as the window gets smaller.

I've written the following CSS:

```
@media (max-width:420px){
     #header #logo{
        width:60%;
        float:left;
        background:red;
    }

    #header #logo #image{
        margin:5%;
        width:20%;
        float:left;
        background:green;
    }

    #header #nav{
        width:40%;
        float:left;
        background:purple;
    }

    #header #nav #search{
        max-width:33%;
        float:left;
    }

    #header #nav #account{
        max-width:33%;
        float:left;
    }

    #header #nav #menu{
        max-width:33%;
        float:left;
    }
 }
```

And the HTML to go with it:

```
<div id="logo">
        <div id="image">
            s
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
        <div id="search">
            <img src="assets/images/mobile-search.png"/> 
        </div>
        <div id="account">
            <img src="assets/images/mobile-account.png"/> 
        </div>
        <div id="menu">
            <img src="assets/images/mobile-menu.png"/> 
        </div>
    </div>
```

The images aren't resizing as I'm resizing the window.
What is the correct CSS syntax to achieve this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apply `max-width` to your images.

```css
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VBHhD/

I would also use an unordered list for navigation, but that's just me.

Comment: Another Tip: apply the img attribute max-width only to the img that you want to be resized ;)

Comment: I always use links for navigation, makes the whole thing clickable without js, thus making it possible to center-mouse-click.

Comment: They are just images to click that will use JS to display menus etc.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS You are using media query for a max-width of 420px which is a mobile view. Have you tried to resize your browser at a very low level?    @media (max-width: 420px){
     #header #nav #search img,#header #nav #account img,#header #nav #menu img {
  width:50%;

} http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kchqg