# responsive displaying image inside of percentage div

Tags: html, css

I have been struggling to find the answer. Is there any possible way to responsieve displaying image element when I resize the percentage div element window?

**css**

```
div{
    width:60%;
    height:400px;
}
div > img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    background:tomato
}
```

**html**

```
<div>
    <img src="" alt="" />
</div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sxzwrmr8/1/)

Thank you

Comment: you can do using js. Not sure about using only css

Comment: @Panther Js will not suits my code actually..... is it impossible with only css???

Comment: can you explain more what you mean with `responsive displaying image`? Or the expected results that you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17762957/responsive-images ?

Comment: @codyogden no it is not...

Comment: What is your expected result and what are your actual results?

Comment: @NormanBreau I need to display image with `min-width:100%` inside of div element which it is width with percentage and when I recieze the window it should not be stretched

Comment: You'll need to provide some screenshots of what you're expecting to happen and what's actually happening. There are a few valid answers below which you're saying "don't work" without saying why.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your styles with the below code, and try.

```
div > img {
  width: 100%;
  background: tomato;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `min-width`?

Comment: because div elements width recponsive with min-height

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with media Query to Set Different height and Width Devices`s Diffrent Height and Width Like Follows

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
        div {
            width:60%;
            height:150px;
        }
        img{
            width:60%;
            height:150px;
        }
    }
 @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
        div {
            width:70%;
            height:450px;
        }
        img{
            width:60%;
            height:300px;
        }
    }
```

Here two different style sheet has been specified for two different devices or screen area the first div and images only applies in those devices/screen area on which minimum width is 300 px and another will apply on those devices/screen area whose minimum resolution is 768px

for more information on mediaquery follow link
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: then width:100 % is only option from my side or you should go for svg images because if you set images in % then height or width need to be adjust according to that and in case of px diffrent resolution will set different appearance

Answer (score 0):

Use `max-width:100%`.

```
div > img{
    max-width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    /*min-width:100%;*/
    background:tomato
}
```

```css
  div{
    width:60%;
    height:400px;
}
div > img{
    max-width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:100%;
    /*min-width:100%;*/
    background:tomato;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://css-tricks.com/wp-content/csstricks-uploads/fullpagebackground.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: please remove min-width.

Comment: I really need it because if I remove my element width not show

Answer (score 0):

CSS

```
div {
    height: 400px; /* or whatever value you need here */
    width: 60%;  /* or whatever value you need here */
}

div > img {
    /*  Image will scale down proportionally so 
        it will fit inside its container.
        But if the image is smaller than the container,
        Then it won't stretch to fit the container.

        Note: min-width will force the image to stretch
        You also cannot have width or height specifically set either.
    */
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sxzwrmr8/4/

Comment: That's fine, the div can be whatever size it needs to be. It''s the max-width & max-height on the image that really counts.

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to do is make the height shrink in proportion to the width, I just wouldn't set any `height` attribute at all:

```
div > img{
    width:100%;
    min-width:100%;
    background:tomato
}
```

[**JSFiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/sxzwrmr8/2/)

If you really want to have some control over the height, I'd recommend putting a simple `vw` as the `height` value--assuming the parent `div` really takes up the whole width of the screen like that.  And then specify a fixed `min-height`:

```
div > img{
    width:100%;
    height:60vw;
    min-height:60px;
    min-width:60px;
    background:tomato
}
```

[**JSFiddle Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/sxzwrmr8/3/)

Comment: I can't make the height shrik then background will not change it should be responsieve according to div http://jsfiddle.net/sxzwrmr8/5/

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use **max-width : 100%** for images when making an responsive sites.

**max-width: 100%** would not allow the width of the image to go beyond the width of the outer div and its own width, but if you want that the image always take the full width then use

**div img { width: 100% }**